# Getting byte values from an array and merging them.

Tags: c++, objective-c, arrays

I have a bluetooth module which is sending a 10 **BYTE** array packet to my phone.

I need to get the first two bytes (0, 1) and merge them together and send them to a graph viewer.  (0 = high byte 1 = low byte).

The bytes are 12bits long.

This is my attempt so far:

```
// streamDelegate gave us some data, hand it over to print out
 - (void)receivedData:(uint8_t *)data length:(NSUInteger)len {

uint16_t iChanI = 0;
uint16_t iChanQ = 0;

iChanI = ((data[0] <<8) + data[1]);
iChanQ = ((data[4] <<8) + data[5]);

[sView Update: iChanI : iChanQ];
[sView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

I am unsure if unit8_t is the correct format for the data coming in.

Currently the values outputted from the graph are much larger than I would expect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So far this looks good.  uint8_t is a reasonable type for this kind of operation and you should not run into any surprises with signed numbers and bit shifting this way.  Are you sure the "[sView Update: iChanI : iChanQ];" is correct (my objective-C is a bit rusty, but I can't remember calls with two unnamed parameters)

Comment: sView update is outputting a two channel graph. Am i shifting the data correctly, should it be 8 or 12?

Comment: "the bytes are 12 bits long"? That's not a byte, then, is it? [I'm intentionally ignoring the  C standard definition that says that "a char is a byte, and char's can be any size", because I seriously doubt this code is running on a machine with 12, 24 or 36-bit words that uses 12 bits per character]

Comment: What do you mean by "the bytes are 12 bits long"? do you mean that the 10 bytes array is made of 120bit in total? If so, which I doubt, then uint8_t were rather inapropriate here.

Comment: Sorry the iChanI and iChanQ are 12 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have the wrong endian (Which byte is most significant).  So try

```
iChanI = ((data[1] <<8) + data[0]);
```

and/or
you have unexpected data in the 4 MSBits of iChanI.  Zero these bits:

```
iChanI &= 0x0FFF;
```

Together

```
iChanI = ((data[1] <<8) + data[0]) & 0x0FFF;
```

Do the same for `iChanQ`.

---

You could instead create a type

```
typedef struct {
  uint16_t iChanI;
  uint16_t spare1;
  uint16_t iChanQ;
  uint16_t spare3;
  uint16_t spare4;
  } PhonePAcket_t;  // Ten byte packet

(void)receivedData:(uint8_t *)data length:(NSUInteger)len {
  const PhonePAcket_t *pp = (const PhonePAcket_t*) data;
  uint16_t iChanI = pp->iChanI & 0x0FFF;
  uint16_t iChanQ = pp->iChanQ & 0x0FFF;

 [sView Update: iChanI : iChanQ];
 [sView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I avoided bit arrays, but they could be used.
Packing attributes may be needed.  I am not familiar enough with details of your situation.